# How I can show custom label in Google Chrome URL Bar?

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How I can add custom label-badge in Google Chrome URL bar like on chrome://version/ page (left side, the Chrome word). Or other example extensions page (eg Google Translate have unique name on left side).

I can't find any information of this, but there a lot of antidetection software which are have this feature, for example multiloginapp or sessionbox

It possible to add this label by JavaScript API / command line flags?
If not maybe already exist fork of Chromium with feature?

[image]

Comment: No, it's not possible and there's no such API.

Comment: The closest alternative would be an [address bar button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Page_actions)

Comment: @MerveSahin thank you. I'm asking about google chrome, as I remember in chrome this API was dissabled few years ago. But still possible to change dynamical extension icon

Comment: @TomGola The browser compatibility in [pageAction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction) indicates that it is supported in chrome. And I myself can also confirm it, as I have developed it for chrome.